# How to create Java web application using Struts and GlassFish?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, struts, java-ee-7

I can not find any resources on how to create a simple (Hello World) web application using Struts and GlassFish in Eclipse. The best thing I found was [this](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html). They are however not using GlassFish, and so I do not have the XML files they are talking about. What to do now?

Edit:
I'm Talking about both, the `struts-config.xml`  and `web.xml` file. I do not have them in my project. Should I add them? Where? I have `glassfish-web.xml`.

Comment: What xml do you mean `struts-config.xml` or `web.xml`?

Comment: adding java-ee to your tags and not just java is a start :). I find your tutorial not too bad. Scroll to the very end of it and it shows you the whole structure and the files you need to create.

Comment: @pmminov you are right, sorry. Edited

Comment: no worries, as I said, look at the end of your tutorial, it shows where those files need to be on your tree.

Comment: @pmminov so should I simply create those t wo files and delete glassfish-web.xml? Or leave it alone?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054371/glassfish-web-xml-vs-sun-web-xml-vs-web-xml, ee projects use what is called a deployment descriptor. Personally I have never used anything other than web.xml

Comment: Go through this step wise tutorial for struts application with deployment in GlassFish server http://agafix.org/struts2-hello-world-example-eclipse-maven2/

Comment: Can you think of using [Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/) with the [convention plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/convention-plugin.html)? It requires almost zero XML configurations in the `struts.xml` configuration file. All we can do using annotations in action classes themselves. The convention plugin by default, assumes that all results are stored in `WEB-INF/content` (this can however, be changed, if needed). Struts2 is comparatively simpler and easier than Struts1 (apart from a few simple applications in Struts1, I did not try much in Struts1 though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just googled for a while and found this tutorial series from part 1 to 7.

Here is the first two parts in the series:

- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-creating-struts-application-in-eclipse/

In this second part of the tutorial series, you find all 7 parts of the series in the top :)

- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-struts-2-application-eclipse-example/

Hope it can help you!

Comment: thank you but it has the same problem, the XML files in this tutorial are incompatibile with what I need

Comment: @DaveNewton if I try it with the same filed I get error 404. Glassfish creates glassfish-web.xml file, which has different structure than web.xml, if I delete glassfish-web.xml the application simply does not start