# spring2.5 Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name "xxx" available as request attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

please help me... i'm using spring 2.5 
i got a error message. this

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
Here **URL** //localhost:8080/Projectname/Main_login.jsp

**stack trace**

```
severe: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag.doStartTagInternal(BindTag.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
    at org.apache.jsp.Main_005flogin_jsp._jspService(Main_005flogin_jsp.java from :86)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

**LoginController.java**

    package controller;


    import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import logic.Schedule;
    import logic.User;

    import org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
    import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;
    import utils.WebConstants;


@Controller
public class LoginController extends SimpleFormController {
    private Schedule scheduleService;

    public void setScheduleService(Schedule scheduleService) {
        this.scheduleService = scheduleService;
    }

    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, 
            Object command,BindException bindException)throws Exception{
        User user=(User)command;
        try{

            User loginUser = this.scheduleService.getUserByUserInfo(user.getUserID(),user.getPassword());


            WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, WebConstants.USER_KEY, loginUser);
            ModelAndView modelAndView = 
                new ModelAndView(getSuccessView(),"loginUser",loginUser);
            return modelAndView;

        } catch(DataRetrievalFailureException e) {
            bindException.reject("error.login");
            return showForm(request,response,bindException);
        }
    }
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="EUC-KR"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" 
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</value>  
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scheduler</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username"><value>root</value></property>
        <property name="password"><value>1234</value></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Calendar -->
    <bean id="scheduleService" class="logic.ScheduleImpl">
        <property name="userCatalog">
            <ref bean="userCatalog"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- UserCatalog -->
    <bean id="userCatalog" class="logic.UserCatalogImpl">
        <property name="userDao">
            <ref bean="userDao"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- UserDao -->
    <bean id="userDao" class="dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Validator -->
    <bean id = "loginValidator" class="utils.LoginValidator" />
    <bean id = "user" class="logic.User">
    </bean>

    <!-- MessageSource -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
    class = "org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list><value>messages</value></list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Scheduler-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="EUC-KR" ?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "_//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <!-- Handler Mapping -->
    <bean id="handlerMapping" 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/Main_login.html">loginController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Controller -->
    <bean id="loginController" class="controller.LoginController" >
        <property name="sessionForm"><value>false</value></property>
        <property name="commandName"><value>user</value></property>
        <property name="commandClass"><value>logic.User</value></property>
        <property name="validator"><ref bean="loginValidator"/></property>
        <property name="formView"><value>Main_login</value></property>
        <property name="successView"><value>index</value></property>
        <property name="scheduleService"><ref bean="scheduleService"/></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- ViewResolver -->
    <bean id="internalResourceViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
    </property>
        <property name="prefix">
        <value>WebContent</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**User.java**

```
package logic;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable{
    private String userID;
    private String password;
    private String userName;

    // setter / getter () skip
}
```

**Main_login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
    pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<%@page session = "false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"  %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
<title>Family Scheduler - login page </title>
</head>
<body>


<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="./image/img_main_log.png" alt="logo"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>　</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

        <form id="form1" action="Main_login.html" method="post">
        <spring:bind path="user">
            <font color="red"><c:out value="${status.errorMessage}"/></font>
        </spring:bind>
        <font color="red"><c:out value="${loginErrorMsg}"/></font>
        id:
        <spring:bind path="user.userID">
            <input type="text" 
            name="<c:out value ="${status.expression}"/>" 
            value="<c:out value ="${status.value}"/>"
            maxlength="20" style="margin-left:16px" >
            <font color="red"><c:out value="${status.errorMessage}"/></font>
        </spring:bind> <br/>

         p/w:
         <spring:bind path="user.password">
            <input type="password"
            name="<c:out value ="${status.expression}"/>" 
            value="<c:out value ="${status.value}"/>" maxlength="20">
            <font color="red"><c:out value="${status.errorMessage}"/></font>
        </spring:bind>
                <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="Join_Us.html">sing up </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you paste your code controller, jsp and xml bean declaration

Comment: Spring 2.5 is quite old / buggy. Insist upon upgrading it to a newer / later version.

Comment: I paste my code. I think so. but I have to use spring 2.5

Comment: Paste the full stack trace and the structure of the URL you are requesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are submitting a form that is trying to bind a user object to the request.. your request method signature needs to look something like:

```
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult binding, HttpSession session) {
```

I think you also need to set the User object in the request on the initial get call that displays the form.

E.g.

```
model.addAttribute("user", new User());
```

Check out this tutorial for more info:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-form-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks alot. in addtion, I'm using glassfish WAS. in my project, there are sun_web.xml . is it ok? I think it maybe fault... it makes me crazy.. I watched "Spring works correctly.But The UserBean is instanciated by JSF. So Spring did not notice that the Bean will created and cannot inject the service." at other page.

Comment: I havent used that Glassfish server, you can see here for some info on the different web xml files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054371/glassfish-web-xml-vs-sun-web-xml-vs-web-xml. Id wager that you dont need the sun_web.xml though and you should in fact configure the web.xml file to point to the Spring MVC dispatcher only so you can map the requests using Spring.

Comment: Thanks colws! I makes it. The problem is that my project's context root, and directory structure. anyway Thanks!!!