# Netbeans created project has no glassfish-web.xml

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I have a Spring/Glassfish project created using a NetBeans wizard at the start of the year (so I don't remember the exact settings used to create it).

The strange thing though is that there is no `glassfish-web.xml` file inside the project whereas a different project created at the same time does have one.

Why would a project not have a `glassfish-web.xml` file?

I've been investigating a character encoding issue and some responses suggest adding to `glassfish-web.xml`:

```
 <sun-web-app>
      <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
 </sun-web-app>
```

However I can't do that as I don't have a `glassfish-web.xml`!

Is it possible to add one? If so what do I need to do in order to make sure it is read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is included after project creation depends on the archetype (means the project template you have chosen) which is used. Some archetypes already contain a `glassfish-web.xml`, most of them don't.

You can easily create one by right-clicking on the folder `WEB-INF`, then choose `New` and `GlassFish Descriptor`. If this option is not available you may have to add the JSF facet to your project (right-click the project and add JSF in the frameworks tab).

You can also create the file manually, just create a new xml file in the `WEB-INF` folder, give the appropriate name and paste the desired content into the file.

**See also:**

- [glassfish-web.xml vs sun-web.xml vs web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054371/glassfish-web-xml-vs-sun-web-xml-vs-web-xml)